# eclipse errors while running custom code

Tags: java, eclipse, documentum6.5

While adding custom jar files in the project and executing some java code I am getting this error any idea how to solve this .There is no error in code ,it was running smoothly before this happen.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature 
at com.util.DfExSession.connectToDocbase(DfExSession.java:18)## Heading ##
at com.console.TestConsole.main(TestConsole.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.Signature
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Well then, the jar file containing org.aspecth.lang.Signature is not in your classpath.  Please look at the "related" links on the right, or search in SO before posting a question.  You will probably find a relevant link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like the `aspectjrt.jar` is missing in your classptah. Download & add it to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks ,After addition of jar I have changed the class path and it works.